# Installing Fiona on python virtualenv using Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pip, fiona

I created a virtual environment of python on my Windows computer. I successfully downloaded GDAL 2.4.1 and linked it to python, I am trying to install Fiona using

```
pip install fiona
```

but I get this:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\marcb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dua0wlxg\fiona\
```

Any thoughts on what to do? I need to use the virtualenv and not conda (I already have it successfully installed on anaconda)

Comment: You can try and install `geopandas` which have `fiona` as dependency. Worked for me.

Comment: I get the same when doing that since it is also trying to install fiona.

Comment: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona#windows